# Can flexbox fill the entire screen without access to the 'body'?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In my situation I'm not able to apply flex to the body tag. Can I achieve the same effect (sticky header/footer with the flexbox taking up the full screen) without applying css to the body tag. Here is the relevant code. I commented out the body css that achieves the effect I want.

Thanks,
Matt

```css
/*html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
*/
.flex-body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}



.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}
.col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/* TEMP CODE FOR THIS TEST, REMOVE FOR ACTUAL USE
*/
body {
  text-align: center;
}

*{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
<header class="header">
 <section class="content">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">
   Upper Left
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   Upper Middle
  </div>
  <div class="col">
   Upper Right
  </div>
 </div>

 </section>
</header>
<main class="main">
 <nav class="nav">
  Nav
 </nav>
 <section class="content">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
    Upper Left
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    Upper Middle
   </div>
   <div class="col">
    Upper Right
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   Middle
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   Lower
  </div>
 </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Height and min-height in percent only work if the parent element has an explicit height - so `.flex-body { min-height: 100%; }` won’t work if you can not specify the height of body and html. But you could try `100vh` instead ...

Comment: height:100% needs a parent with an height too, so % can be calculated . here body has no height. in order to work you need : `html,body {height:100%}` where html calculates height from window's browser. .flex-body can use this height for height or min-height. Note that IE has issue with min-height in this case. add to body `display:flex;flex-direction:column;` many questions here about those 2

Answer (score 2):

you can also imbricate flex boxe and use flex shorthands to fill entire parent's height or width . **But this means to include html & body** .

This way you do need to deal with height/width and margins/paddings. The browser will deal with it itself.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

body,
.flex-body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;/* no need anymore to deal with height/width */
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  /* mind this */
  /*overflow:auto; */ /* can come handy here if you want to keep footer in view */
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}


/* TEMP CODE FOR THIS TEST, REMOVE FOR ACTUAL USE
*/

body {
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-body">
  <header class="header">
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          Upper Left
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Upper Middle
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Upper Right
        </div>
      </div>

    </section>
  </header>
  <main class="main">
    <nav class="nav">
      Nav
    </nav>
    <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          Upper Left
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Upper Middle
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          Upper Right
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Middle
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        Lower
      </div>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a min-height of 100vh to the flex container:

```
.flex-body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Then it will be at least as tall as the browser’s viewport (but will be allowed to grow taller if necessary).